# Global animation callback or animation eventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a couple of functions I would like to run whenever any element in my DOM is animated using jQuery (e.g. slideToggle()) and I am hoping there is a way to run these functions without having to use a callback on every single function.

So I'm wondering if there is an event listener that I can apply to the document that will run whenever an animation is complete or some kind of global callback that I can configure somewhere.

Comment: show pls the minimum of your code with animation. or maybe it will help you? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event